What is the correct method to find the intersection of these subspaces?
I have to find the intersection in $\mathbb R^4$ of the subspaces generated by these generators:
$$S1 = span[(1 ,2, 2, 1)^T,(0, 1 ,0, -1)^T]$$
$$S2 = span[(1, 0 ,1, 2)^T,(1 ,2, 1 ,0)^T]$$
I wrote these subspaces in Cartesian and solved the system for the 4 equations and obtained that the intersection is:
$$S1∩S2 = span[(0, 1, 0 ,-1)^T]$$
which verifies that it can be written as linear combinations of S1 and for S2 too.
When i try to do this directly using the generating vectors of $S1$ and $S2$, in the form:
$\alpha$$(1 ,2, 2, 1)^T$+$\beta$$(0 ,1 ,0, -1)^T$ = $\gamma$ $(1, 0, 1, 2)^T$ + $\delta$$(1, 2, 1, 0)^T$
that is: $\alpha$$(1, 2 ,2 ,1)^T$+$\beta$$(0, 1, 0, -1)^T$ - $\gamma$ $(1 ,0, 1, 2)^T$ - $\delta$$(1, 2, 1 ,0)^T$= $0 $
that is:
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & -1 & -1\\
2 & 1 & 0 & -2\\
2 & 0 & -1 & -1\\
1 & -1 & -2 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
When I triangle the matrix I am left with a vector of the form:
$$S1∩S2 = span[(0,-2,1,-1)^T]$$
which is not even a linear combination of the vectors of $S1$ or $S2$ and does not comply with the cartesian equations of those subspaces.

Questions :
What is the problem?. Why doesn't it give me the same vector? or some multiple of that vector? Instead it gives me a vector that is not in those subspaces, what is the problem?

Welcome to MSE. I took the liberty of correcting the small latex problems. Did you understand correctly that you do geometry in $\mathbb R^4$?

You have an error in the last paragraph. You have found that we can choose $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta)=(0,-2,1,-1)$. So a generator for $S_1\cap S_2$ is $\alpha (1,2,2,1)+\beta(0,1,0,-1)=(0,-2,0,2)$ and all is well.
